# Pandas: Calculating column-wise mean yields nulls

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame, `df`, and I'd like to get the mean for columns 180 through the end (not including the last column), only using the first 100K rows.

If I use the whole DataFrame:

```
df.mean().isnull().any()
```

I get `False`

If I use only the first 100K rows:

```
train_means = df.iloc[:100000, 180:-1].mean()
train_means.isnull().any()
```

I get: `True`

I'm not sure how this is possible, since the second approach is only getting the column means for a subset of the full DataFrame.  So if no column in the full DataFrame has a mean of `NaN`, I don't see how a column in a subset of the full DataFrame can.

For what it's worth, I ran:

```
df.columns[df.isna().all()].tolist()
```

and I get: `[]`.  So I don't think I have any columns where every entry is `NaN` (which would cause a `NaN` in my `train_means` calculation).

Any idea what I'm doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you produce a [mcve]?

Comment: @coldspeed Unfortunately, this is using proprietary data, so I can't do that :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try look at

```
 (df.iloc[:100000, 180:-1].isnull().sum()==100000).any()
```

If this return `True` , which mean you have a columns' value is all `NaN` in the first 100000 rows

And Now let us explain why you get all `notnull` when do the `mean` to the whole dataframe , since `mean` have `skipna`  ***default***  as `True` so it will drop `NaN` before `mean`

Comment: Just to clarify: I _do_ get a `NaN` in my list of column means when I do this: ```train_means = df.iloc[:100000, 180:-1].mean()
train_means.isnull().any()```

Comment: @bclayman return True ?`(df.iloc[:100000, 180:-1].isnull().sum()==100000).any()`

Comment: So that does return True.  However, then I don't understand why `df.columns[df.isna().all()].tolist()` returned no columns...

Comment: @bclayman your data have NaN in the first 10000 rows , that is why , first 10000 rows of the columns  all NaN dose not mean whole columns NaN

Comment: when I'm referring to `df`, that's the entire DataFrame, not just the first 100K rows.  So that's why I'm confused.  Why would `df.columns[df.isna().all()].tolist()` return no columns?

Comment: @bclayman ... since df.mean().isna().any(), return false , which means the whole df each columns at least have one value notnull .

Comment: @bclayman ok that is typo nope I am referring to `mean` `df.mean().isna().any()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189423/discussion-between-bclayman-and-wen-ben).